# Scripts connected to an Image in EggPlant

Tags: automation, refactoring, eggplant

I have LoginButton.png that is being used across the whole suite in different scripts. I want to edit the name or move it to a new folder, without breaking all the scripts. So is there a way to list all the scripts that are using this image or to refactor the name/path across the whole suite?

Find option (Edit>Find) it's the closest to what I want, but it only looks at the open script, not the whole suite, and replaces anything with similar naming convention eg: Find "LoginButton" and replace with "NewButton", if you have "LoginButton", "LoginButton1", "LoginButton2" after the replace you will end up with "NewButton", "NewButton1", "NewButton2", and i just want to change "LoginButton" not "LoginButton1" and  "LoginButton2".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you've found the closest solution. One of Eggplant's major drawbacks is that you're locked into a single, (rather feature-less) IDE. If you're having issues matching other words with your search query, you can try including spaces, i.e. `" LoginButton "`, on the outside of the word.